# Untargetted Bindings in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, guice

In the Guice documentation, there is an [Untargetted Binding example](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/UntargettedBindings) as:

```
bind(MyConcreteClass.class)
   .annotatedWith(Names.named("foo"))
   .to(MyConcreteClass.class);
```

Can someone explain, in plain English, what exactly this is doing and why you would want to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's creating a binding of type `MyConcreteClass` annotated with `@Named("foo")` using the implementation class `MyConcreteClass`. You'd do it if you want to inject that type:

```
@Inject public Bar(@Named("foo") MyConcreteClass object) { ... }
```

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking it was for, but it's nice to have the confirmation.  Thanks.